# R tm package. Where I can find a detailed description of the components of the TermDocumentMatrix? i, j, v

Tags: r, tm

As an example this is a tdm:

```
str(AssociatedPress)
List of 6
$ i       : int [1:302031] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

$ j       : int [1:302031] 116 153 218 272 299 302 447 455 548 597 ...
$ v       : int [1:302031] 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 ...
$ nrow    : int 2246
$ ncol    : int 10473
$ dimnames:List of 2
..$ Docs : NULL
..$ Terms: chr [1:10473] "aaron" "abandon" "abandoned" "abandoning" ...
- attr(*, "Weighting")= chr [1:2] "term frequency" "tf"
- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "DocumentTermMatrix" "simple_triplet_matrix"
```

I have been trying to find the description of these columns $i, $j, $v ... 
Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/slam/docs/as.simple_triplet_matrix

Under `?TermDocumentMatrix`

We see:

```
Value

An object of class TermDocumentMatrix or class DocumentTermMatrix
(both inheriting from a simple triplet matrix in package slam)
containing a sparse term-document matrix or document-term matrix. The
attribute Weighting contains the weighting applied to the matrix.
```

When you click on the link in the statement **both inheriting from a [simple triplet matrix](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/slam/docs/as.simple_triplet_matrix)**:

```
Arguments

i, j    
Integer vectors of row and column indices, respectively.

v   
Vector of values.
```

and...

```
Details
simple_triplet_matrix is a generator for a class of
“lightweight” sparse matrices, “simply” represented by triplets (i,
j, v) of row indices i, column indices j, and values v, respectively.
simple_triplet_zero_matrix and simple_triplet_diag_matrix are
convenience functions for the creation of empty and diagonal
matrices.
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the idea of the sparse matrix, is like giving i,j and the value of those which are non zero.